# when Cucumber values are defined at the end of scenario outline, get an error

Tags: java, testing, cucumber

I'm trying to set a test with Cucumber.
I need the same value in two steps

This ***doesn't*** work:

```
Scenario Outline: print to screen 
Then print a <filename> to screen
Then print again the <filename> and extension <extension> to screen
Examples:
      | filename| extension |
      | abcd    | txt  |
```

The error i get:

```
io.cucumber.core.exception.CucumberException: Step [A] is defined with 1 parameters at xxxxxx(java.lang.String)'.
However, the gherkin step has 0 arguments.
```

Basically says that i must have at least one parameter in the first step..

This ***works***:

```
Scenario Outline: print to screen
Then print a <filename> to screen
Examples:
      | filename |
      | abcd  |
Then print again the <filename> and extension <extension> to screen
Examples:
      | filename | extension |
      | abcd     | txt  |
```

Here are the step-definitions:

```
@Then("print a (.*) to screen")
public void printToScreen(String value) {
...
}


@Then("^print again the (.*) and extension (.*) to screen")
public void printToScreenWithExt(String value, String ext) {
...
}
```

I followed this example:
https://www.baeldung.com/cucumber-scenario-outline#rewriting-features-using-scenario-outlines

thanks..

Comment: Can you add the step definitions?

Comment: @GregBurghardt:  sure, added..

Answer (score 0):

well, i was missing the '^' in the first step,
therefore the error was that there are 0 arguments..